# Cannot start MySQL server with AppleScript - Snow Leopard

Tags: applescript, mysql, apache

I've sucessfully installed MySQL server (5.5.11) on my MAC Snow Leopard. I can start the server using PreferencePane, using command line `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe` but cannot use the same command within AppleScript.

This is the output from running `sudo /user/local/mysql/bin/mysql_safe`:

```
ngocminh@MBP[304]:~$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe 
Password:
110428 09:52:03 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/MBP.local.err'.
110428 09:52:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Apache2 server can be started using the command `sudo apachetl start`, then it could be implemented using an AppleScript script like this:

```
do shell script "apachectl start" password "mypassword" user name "ngocminh" with administrator privileges
```

However, I can't simply do the same for starting mysql server

```
do shell script "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe" password "mypassword" user name "ngocminh" with administrator privileges
```

The apple script result says:

```
"110428 11:03:06 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/MBP.local.err'.
110428 11:03:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
110428 11:03:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/MBP.local.pid ended"
```

Then MySQL server cannot be started!

Would anybody tell what's wrong with my script or I've missed something. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

**-- EDIT 1 --**

Try to run this script instead

```
do shell script "apachectl start" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges do shell script "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

No error reported by AppleScript but MySQL server is still not loaded according to `ps` command

```
ngocminh@MBP[315]:mysql$  ps aux | grep mysql
root      5652   0.0  0.0  2435544    872 s000  T     9:51AM   0:00.04 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
ngocminh 16127   0.0  0.0  2435120    528 s001  R+    2:30PM   0:00.00 grep mysql
ngocminh@MBP[315]:mysql$  ps aux | grep http
ngocminh 16141   0.0  0.0  2425524    172 s001  U+    2:30PM   0:00.00 grep http
ngocminh 16092   0.0  0.0  2452692    644   ??  S     2:29PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
ngocminh 16088   0.0  0.2  2456532   8960   ??  S     2:29PM   0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root     16035   0.0  0.2  2452692   9832   ??  Ss    2:29PM   0:00.43 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

**-- EDIT 2-- PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I found the way around it. Just creat an AppleScript with `sudo` inside for mysql server startup

```
do shell script "apachectl start" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
do shell script "sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I found the way around it. Just create an AppleScript with `sudo` inside for mysql server startup

```
do shell script "apachectl start" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
do shell script "sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this, starting from administrator?

```
do shell script "/sw/sbin/apachectl start" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges do shell script "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

*Source*: http://menial.co.uk/2008/11/16/applescript-for-starting-and-stopping-apache-and-mysql/

Comment: Yes, I did. Although AppleScript doesn't report any error, MySQL server is not started. Please see update on question to see the output of commands.